# Cartopy: order of rendering layers with scatter data

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am trying to plot position of several points (scatter plot) on a map using Cartopy (see code below). When I try to render the plot, data-points are rendered behind LAND-layer. But I want to plot my scatter-data over LAND-layer... What I am doing wrong?

Cartopy: ver. 0.12.x, Matplotlib: ver.1.4.2

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature 

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()) 
ax.set_extent([125, 150, 35, 63])         

ax.stock_img()

ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND) #If I comment this => all ok, but I need 
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.RIVERS)
ax.coastlines()

ax.scatter(yc,xc,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()) #yc, xc -- lists or numpy arrays

plt.show()
```

[image: Points shown under the LAND layer]

[image: Plot without LAND-layer]

Comment: try specifying a numerical `zorder`in your call to scatter.

Comment: Thanks! Setting up "zorder" solves the problem!

Comment: @PaulH - would you mind putting this as an answer?

Comment: @pelson answer has been posted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most, if not all, matplotlib plotting functions take a `zorder` parameter to specify the drawing order.

Lower `zorder`s will be drawn first, and as such higher `zorder`s will appear "on top".

So yeah, pass in `zorder=xxx` to arrange your layers.

Comment: @pelson or @paul-h - I'm just curious, but why is this case? Sort of intuitively I would expect the scatter points to be 'on top' if the `plt.scatter` call is after the `ax.add_feature` calls. I had a similar problem to the OP and have to specify `zorder=2`.

Comment: @decvalts I couldn't tell you without inspecting the cartopy source code to check what the default zorders are. I don't have time for that, so I'll encourage you to do so.